# Affecting a "static" struct in another struct in heap

Tags: c

So I solved my problem, wasn't that hard, but I'm wandering why the first version wasn't working.
So here, an example of my problem :

```
typedef struct a {
    int i;
}   A;

typedef struct b {
    int i;
    A a;
}   B;

typedef B * PB;

PB create_B(int ia, int ib) {
    PB b = malloc(sizeof(B));
    b->i = ib;
    b->a = {ia};
}
```

I get an error from the compiler saying :

> "error: expected expression before ‘{’ token"
>
> at line: b->a = {ia};

But i don't really get what is the problem.

I solved it casting the structure :

```
PB create_B(int ia, int ib) {
    PB b = malloc(sizeof(B));
    b->i = ib;
    b->a = (A){ia};
}
```

But the types are well defined no ? I mean it's kind of obvious to me that {ia} is of type A since b->a is of type A aswell.

I am probably wrong on this last saying (compiler is probably right). So if you have an example where this situation isn't obvious and really need a cast, it would be really appreciated, or jut an explanation at least.

Thank you for your time.

Barioth

PS :
I could have done that too i guess

```
PB create_B(int ia, int ib) {
    PB b = malloc(sizeof(B));
    *b = (B){ib, {ia}};
}
```

But i still need a cast...

Comment: `{ia} is of type A` No, `ia` is of type `int`.

Comment: Hmm, i don't really know, but why does it work in
" *b = (B){ib, {ia}}; "
I mean, in the example, yes, {ia} is of type"int[]" or "int", I don't really know, but if i chose a more complex example, my A struct could have been way more complex than just an int (I just simplified my problem to the maximum).

Comment: Hi Barioth, see the answer from @EricPostpischil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ia}` is not an expression in C and cannot be used in an expression statement.

`{ia}` is part of a syntax for definitions. In a definition, a list of initial values may be given in braces after an `=`. (And the braces may be omitted when initializing a scalar object.) This is a special syntax for initializing in a definition and is not an assignment like using `=` in an expression.

`(A){ia}` is an expression; it is a construct called a compound literal. After a type name in parentheses, initial values are given inside braces. This creates an object of the stated type. That object may then be used  in an expression, such as as the right operand of an assignment.

Comment: So it is literally the same as defining a local variable and copy it into the struct I just allocated, right ?

Comment: @Barioth: Nearly the same. The local variable has a name and can be referred to again. The compound literal has no name. Otherwise, the object is the same.